# Calculate duty cycle of device's on and sleep state to drain coin cell in given amount of time

Tags: batteries, current, duty-cycle, capacity

I am trying to drain a 25 mAh ECR1216 coin cell in 2 days. My device draws 6 mA when on, and about 15 μA when on standby.

I am having a hard time determining a duty cycle for on/standby time to drain the cell in 2 days (it doesn't have to be exact).

Comment: What state of charge does it begin with? What voltage etc.. And, what state of charge marks the end of your experiment?

Comment: battery is coming out of the package so ideally 3v and my voltage regulator will probably not power up at roughly 2.5v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess would be about 4 hours of up-time every 48 hours, but let's do some math to make sure.

Assuming you can get the full 25 mAh from the battery before the voltage drops too far to power your circuit (\$a\$ is the fraction of on-time):

$$25\ \mathrm{mAh} = (a\cdot 6\ \mathrm{mA} + (1-a)\cdot 0.015\ \mathrm{mA})\cdot 48\ \mathrm{h}\Rightarrow\\25 = (6a + 0.015 - 0.015a)\cdot 48 \Rightarrow\\a=0.0845$$

So the duty cycle should be about 8.5%.

Check:

0.0845 · 48 is roughly 4 hours of up time, consuming about 4 · 6 = 24 mAh.

Then there are (1 - 0.0845) · 48 or about 44 hours on stand-by, consuming about 44 · 0.015 = 0.7 mAh.

This adds up to 24 + 0.7 is about 25 mAh.

Note that you will very probably not get the full 25 mAh from the battery before the voltage drops to below the 2.5 V you need (this particular battery's capacity is specified for a discharge down to 2 V). Also, pulsed use versus continuous use will affect capacity slightly.

The [battery's datasheet](https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/cr1216.pdf) or an experiment can tell you how much capacity you can expect when discharging at a given current (and duty cycle) down to a given voltage.

Comment: This is gold, thanks man. I seem to have forgotten my fundamentals